# How to synchronize a Windows database for Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-9.5, windows-server

I have some database (PostgreSQL 9.5) on a Windows server, and I would like this data to be synchronized to a Linux server, that is connected in an application.

Is it possible to synchronize?

Comment: **All** the data or just some tables? How far apart (physically) are the server? How fast is the network between them? Do you just need to make the data "available" on the Linux server - then  [foreign tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html) might be another choice (if just want to "replicate" some tables)

Comment: What do you mean by synchronised? One way? Or both ways? Why do you want to do this? Please describe your environmental and use case a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

A single time syncron can be done by simply dumping the database on the Windows, and piping into a command line postgresql client to your Linux machine:

```
pg_dump --host=your.windows.host --port=5432 --user=you|\
psql --host=your.linux.host --port=5432 --user=you
```

If you are thinking on some type of replication cluster, then it is hard to answer here, but you could [read the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/server-start.html).

There is no major OS-dependence in the storage areas and protocols in PostgreSQL, but these are enough to make the cross-os physical replication impossible ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46603426/1783163)). From PostgreSQL 10, you could use logical replication, or use some [third party solution](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Replication).